# Align items with multiple lines with another element

Tags: html, css

I need to align images and text as in the bottom example; so the image aligns to the top of the text when the text has 2 lines. In my code it's aligning to the center:

```css
.product-legend {
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 210px;
}

.product-legend-img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
}

.product-legend-text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="product-legend-img">img</div>
  <div class="product- legend-text">NEW! this is a test</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="product-legend-img">img</div>
  <div class="product- legend-text">NEW! this is a test of a line with two lines of text</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="product-legend-img">img</div>
  <div class="product- legend-text">More features</div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="product-legend-img">img</div>
  <div class="product- legend-text">Another line</div>
</div>
```

I tried setting the elements as span, and setting a height but I can't seem to vertically-align the images.

Comment: "*as in the bottom example*" - you haven't shown any examples of how it should look, or included any `<img>` elements in the code you provided. Can you show us how it should look? How the elements should be arranged? Also, you have typos in your CSS; the second `<div>` has a space between `product-` and `legend-text`, which means the CSS declarations for the `.product-legend-text` isn't being applied.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean something like this?

I used a **flexbox** because it's simpler to position the text this way. So the list is displayed in columns (this is not necessarily needed `flex-direction: column` as this is also a lists default as long as the items do not have `display: inline | inline-block`) and the items are displayed in rows (`flex-direction: row` is the default value, so by setting `display: flex` it's a row). Each list-item has (due to `display: flex` & row (again, default value)) the same height. Its childs too meaning image (wrapper, `<picture>`) and the text wrapper (`.text`) have the same height (info: thats not the case if they are displayed in columns). You can position smaller elements like the text with `align-items: start` separately. See [css tricks flexbox guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox) for further info on flexbox.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  // both optional
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
 }

li {
  display: flex;
  align-items: start;
}

picture, .text {
  width: 50%;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.text { padding-left: 1rem; }

img { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <picture>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/512x512/000/eee.gif&text=your+image" alt="img" />
    </picture>
    <div class="text">
      <h2>headline</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <picture>
      <img src="https://dummyimage.com/512x512/eee/000.gif&text=your+image" alt="img" />
    </picture>
    <div class="text">
      <h2>headline</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need `display: flex;` on the parent, remove the space from the clasname, and get rid of `position: absolute;`

```css
.product-legend {
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 210px;
}

.product-legend-img {
  display: inline-block;
  /*position: absolute;*/
}

.product-legend-text {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 12px;
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: 40px;
}

.product {
  display: flex;
  
  /* border for demonstraition purposes only */
  border-top: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-legend-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200"></div>
  <div class="product-legend-text">NEW! this is a test</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-legend-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200"></div>
  <div class="product-legend-text">NEW! this is a test of a line with two lines of text</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-legend-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200"></div>
  <div class="product-legend-text">More features</div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="product-legend-img"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200"></div>
  <div class="product-legend-text">Another line</div>
</div>
```